# Should the popular-notable-famous question criteria be adjusted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, view-badges

[In another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215494/allow-users-to-vote-for-badge-type-changes) I asked about how badge criteria could be adjusted  and the comments suggested that it might be simpler to just ask a specific question about a specific badge.

I think that the question badges popular-notable-famous being awarded for the question being viewed a set number of times should now be made more difficult to achieve given how SO dominates Google.

> Gold badges recognize important contributions from members of the
>   community. They are rarely awarded.

Over 100,000 gold badges have been awarded for some questions being looked at a lot - which does not suggest that this is a 'rarely awarded' badge. Instead of 1,000-2,500-10,000 is a distribution of 1k-40k-1million more realistic now we're five years in.

What should these badges be awarded for?

Comment: This does make sense now. Maybe make the number fluid rather than fixed, i.e. dependant on the average page views. This will also make it more fair for other, smaller, sites.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Making badge awards automatically adjust to flex with site usage is exactly what I've just what I've been trying to say in an excessive outburst of thousands of words today!

Comment: Yep, if you can come with a specific formula feel free to post it as new answer and who knows, maybe the team will consider such a thing. :)

Comment: Any number that makes sense for the trilogy will be unattainable on most other sites.  We need to either leave it alone or make it dynamic somehow.

Answer (score 4):

OK then how about if popular-notable-famous questions are awarded based on @ShadowWizard 's suggestion and given based on how popular they are *relative* to the rest of the site:

- Bronze: awarded for the top 20% most viewed questions
- Silver: awarded for the top 1% most viewed questions
- Gold: awarded for the top 0.01% most viewed questions

Then this criteria would fit on any stackexchange site.  On Stackoverflow with 6.4m questions the awards would change thus:

- BRONZE Popular questions currently 1,300,000 awarded would be largely unchanged
- SILVER Notable questions currently 554,000 awarded would fall to 64,000 awards
- GOLD Famous questions currently 108,000 awarded would fall to 600-700 awards

Which seems a more reasonable gold-silver-bronze structure.

Comment: This seems to penalise new questions relative to old ones though.

Comment: I agree it's not perfect - but is it better than the current system where almost every question on the popular tags generates a gold badge after a couple of years?  Where 1 question in every 50 generates a gold badge eventually?

Comment: Well wouldn't a fairer criteria (that also avoids that) be "got x views in a year"? With an absolute number a new question on SO needs to counteract 5 years worth of page views to catch up with an old question.

Comment: @MartinSmith You may be right - add an answer and put it to the great unwashed on meta

Comment: So this means that if questions become older and maybe obsolete now, the badge would be removed? Is this intended?

Comment: If you gain a gold badge award through upvoting, the number of gold badges you have don't change if you suddenly no longer qualify (eg if a tag was removed taking you below a threshold or you were downvoted) - but your next gold badge will not increase the count.  This is the current behaviour and it seems reasonable that this would cover this idea.

Comment: I'd make the Silver and Gold numbers slightly higher (say 3% and .5%).