# Should we acknowledge 100k views questions?

Tags: discussion, badges, view-badges

SE awards gold badges for famous questions that reach 10,000 views, and gold badges for answers that have been upvoted 100 times. But what about those questions that have reached an impressive **100,000** views (100k)?

Shouldn't the original poster receive a special acknowledgement from the community? After all, numbers are physical proof that the question is definitely popular, and one that is shared by visitors outside the SE network.

On EL&U there are several questions that have gone beyond the 100K landmark, or are in proximity of hitting it. The following are only a sample

1. [Is it "bear" or "bare" with me?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/is-it-bear-or-bare-with-me) **929k**   (Yes, really!)
2. ["Dieing" vs "dying"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38524/dieing-vs-dying) *536k*
3. [Which expressions can be used to close an email?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332/which-expressions-can-be-used-to-close-an-email) *459k*
4. ["Lunch" vs. "dinner" vs. "supper" — times and meanings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22446/lunch-vs-dinner-vs-supper-times-and-meanings) *361k*
5. [When should "no problem" replace "you're welcome" as a response to "thank you"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146671/when-should-no-problem-replace-youre-welcome-as-a-response-to-thank-you) *291k*
6. ["Which" vs. "what" — what's the difference and when should you use one or the other?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-ot) *232k*
7. ["Worse comes to worst" or "worst comes to worst"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9141/worse-comes-to-worst-or-worst-comes-to-worst) *208k*
8. [When should I use an em-dash, an en-dash, and a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen) *199k*
9. [Difference between "résumé" and "CV"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61338/difference-between-r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9-and-cv) *155k*
10. [When should you use "despite" over "inspite", and vice versa?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21153/when-should-you-use-despite-over-inspite-and-vice-versa) *134k*

And even on SE Meta I found the following 100k questions

1. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) *282k*
2. [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) *170k*
3. [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) *139k*
4. [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) *119k*
5. [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) *114k*

### Handy Tip

Not necessarily the questions which have been upvoted the most attain 100k views.

Thanks to [Shadow Wizard's tip](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266589/should-we-acknowledge-100k-views-questions#comment864933_266591), I discovered that on EL&U there are 41 questions  which have reached the 100K milestone that have earned between one and ten upvotes. [Search on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A100000..20000000%20score%3A0..10)

**Discussion**

I am not suggesting that questions that reach 10,000 views should no longer be awarded a gold badge, but I do believe that a post that has reached a 100k visits is something a bit special and out of the ordinary. I don't know  which form should this recognition take. I am hoping that the community can come up with some suggestions. What about a platinum badge?

Perhaps we can also discuss the flabbergasting 1m landmark. I don't know if that pinnacle has been achieved in Stack Overflow, but EL&U has a strong contender.

---

**EDIT**
It's been brought o my attention that this post may be a duplicate of: [Platinum Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/platinum-badges)
First of all, I am not asking SE to install platinum badges across the board.

> Should there be a new level of badges added above gold, i.e `Platinum` badges?

It is nevertheless true that gold badges are losing their lustre over time, and I strongly believe that view numbers speak louder than the number of upvotes a question receives, especially when it hits the infamous  <sub><sup>**HOT NETWORK QUESTIONS**</sup></sub>

I've clearly identified that a notable number of questions have reached and surpassed the 100k views landmark, whereas the duplicate suggested a hypothetical 250k views benchmark. Which is also a possibility, but I think that number is much rarer across the SE network. My suggestion, a platinum badge, was only that, a suggestion. I could not come up with a better idea,  therefore I am asking the community if they agree that these questions should be **recognized** in some way. Maybe on the question page a new tab could be introduced, questions with highest number of views.  I'm just throwing the ball in the court, and see if it bounces. If nothing else, six years later, maybe the time is ripe to discuss this feature.

---

This feature request is not a duplicate of the following meta posts

1. [Should the popular-notable-famous question criteria be adjusted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215497/should-the-popular-notable-famous-question-criteria-be-adjusted)
2. [Will all questions eventually become popular, notable and famous? Do we have a problem with that?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123050/will-all-questions-eventually-become-popular-notable-and-famous-do-we-have-a-p?rq=1)

Comment: definitely related, I admit but this is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M could you please explain why my question is an exact duplicate? I can see they are related but they are not identical to one another. Is just the mere mention of *platinum badge* suffice to close this question?

Comment: Mari-Lou this has been discussed numerous times in different variations. If you like, I can change and choose another one, like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185275/a-new-harder-type-of-badge?s=6|0.5573) or [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101592/one-badge-to-rule-them-all?s=3|1.3355). Even though they're worse phrased than yours, the rationale remains the same: There are no 'milestone indicators' above the gold badge thresholds and there aren't going to be any.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M those are horrendous questions! I am not suggesting SE replace the milestones, or change the names of badges. I am asking whether 100k views should be acknowledged in some way. I clearly stated: *I don't know which form should this recognition take*, I am asking the community what they think. Give this request time and an  opportunity to be viewed, if nobody posts an answer by Tuesday, I will voluntarily close the question.

Comment: Removed feature-request tag to make this distinct from those other questions. I now agree this is a worthwhile discussion to have. I can't retract my flag though. :|

Comment: On some sites 100k is not that unusual, I have 15 100k+ questions on Arqade. It is much easier to get many views there  than on most other sites.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-you-undo-the-last-commit) on StackOverflow has been viewed 2.3m times.

Comment: @MadScientist there must be a plethora of "famous questions" on that site then! Don't you think a distinction should be made between a post that is visited 10,000 times and one that has reached 250,000 views? As seen in my question, EL&U also has its share of 250k views, but I suspect on SE Gardening (for instance) this number will be extremely difficult to attain.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M if you agree it's not dupe better delete the auto comment.

Answer (score 13):

No, I don't think we should.

Question with so many views usually also get many upvotes so it means 6 badges already: two gold, two silver, and two bronze, for the views and upvotes. Having yet another one would be hardly noticed.

Adding to that the reputation gained from upvotes, this is way more than enough acknowledgement from the community.

The only thing that might still stand out above what we currently have is Platinum Badges, as discussed in the [non-dupe request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/platinum-badges) but in my opinion Jeff and Shog9 answers there are correct, and we don't really need another set of badges.

Comment: You make it sound that the questioner gets these badges very quickly, but before a question hits 10,000 views, a year or more may pass. And before 100,000 views we're talking between two and six years. As for the upvotes, that is an interesting observation. The EL&U ones I listed  have been taken from the most upvoted questions, but they were found in the first ten pages showing fifty results. If a question has received ten upvotes but has been visited over 100k times, the question deserves some form of recognition. How does one find these posts?

Comment: Time isn't a factor in my opinion, but you might have a point about question with 100k views but only 10 upvotes. To find those, you can use the search, there's "views" advanced search operator.

Comment: [Here is the search on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A100000..20000000+score%3A0..9), 117 questions with more than 100k views and less than 10 score.

Comment: Oh, is that how you do it? I would never have known. Thanks for the "query" tip? Is it a query? Whatever.

Comment: Sorry about the query stuff, thought search didn't have "views" operator so was going to suggest using [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) and run SQL query against the raw data. :)

Comment: +1 for the tip, on EL&U there are 41 questions that fit that search. Thank you!

Comment: @Mari-LouA cheers, now need to decide my opinion about what we can do with such questions. :-)

Comment: I've gotten 10k views on a 0 score question. No vote badges for me there, unfortunately :( http://superuser.com/q/829739/333963

Comment: And in many cases also one more gold and one more silver (favorite and stellar)

Answer (score 3):

I think the "impact" score covers this just fine. If having the question view count up in the stratosphere doesn't give you enough of a good feeling, seeing that "people reached" number high as well certainly should.

Badges should generally reward things you can strive for. Asking a question with a zillion views is a combination of luck and ... well, being the first to ask something fairly obvious. All of the questions in your list are ones that *someone* was gonna ask sooner or later, even without the encouragement of a badge. I don't think we *really* want to reward people scheming to ask more obvious questions in the hopes of getting a gigaviews (or whatever) badge.